# Sabre: How to pass Frequent Flyer Number in PNR

Tags: sabre

I would like to know how to pass Frequent Flyer's number in case 2 different Airlines.

Do I need to pass Airline wise i.e Segment wise, or can I pass for Marketing Airline.

For Instance: 
Say Marketing Airline is "9W" and Suppose 2 connecting Airlines are "9W" and "AI", so in this case, will it be ok if I just pass for "9W" (Marketing Airline) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think passing MarketingAirline in ProgramID should be OK.

according to Sabre documentation, you can pass frequent flyer number using PassengerDetailsRQ when creating PNR with this XML element:

```
    <CustLoyalty MembershipID="155P9B76" NameNumber="1.1" ProgramID="XX"
    SegmentNumber="1" TravelingCarrierCode="YY"/>
```

The thing you have to know that you can't combine SegmentNumber element with TravellingCarrierCode. In your case, you have two different airlines to ticket but you want pass the frequent flyer number to only one of these, then you can do:

```
<CustLoyalty MembershipID="155P9B76" NameNumber="1.1" ProgramID="XX" TravelingCarrierCode="XX"/>
```

ProgramID is the airline that you want to pass the frequent flyer number, TravellingCarrierCode can be same or different (due to operating / marketing airline differentiation). NameNumber stands for passenger I guess, I didn't have exact information for that so I don't want to give you wrong information about that attribute.

The schema you should follow in request is:

PassengerDetailsRQ --> TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ --> CustomerInfo --> CustLoyalty

Regards.